# Django import export: update without add

Tags: django, django-import-export

I'm using 'django import export' (DIE) for importing and updating some data.

Import process starts from checking exists objects in DB, searching by values in ID-field, and if row with ID from import file not found - new entre will be created.  How can i made "update only" scenario, where if 'id key' not found in DB, row will be skipped (not added new)?

my model.py

```
class Size(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True, null=False, blank=False)
    height = models.SmallIntegerField()
    width = models.SmallIntegerField()


class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True, null=False, blank=False)
    vendor_code = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(null=False, blank=False)
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size, verbose_name=u'Size')
```

in resource.py

```
class ProductSyncResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = ProductVariant
        import_id_fields = ('vendor_code',)
        fields = ('vendor_code', 'price',)
        export_order = ('vendor_code', 'price', 'status', )
        skip_unchanged = True
        report_skipped = True
        dry_run = True
```

import table (xls)

[image]

If vendor_code 'Tк-12856' (Cell A3) will be not found, then DIE will try to add this row, and:

1. We will get error from DB (foreignKey check for column 'size')
2. I don't need to add this row to DB in my 'update scenario'

Answer (score 3):

Finally i got it by overriding `skip_row`. Fields now can be 'null=False' and will be imported only rows with known `import_id_field` values.

```
class VariantSyncResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = ProductVariant
        import_id_field = 'vendor_code'
        import_id_fields = ('vendor_code',)
        fields = ('vendor_code', 'price', 'status', )
        export_order = ('vendor_code', 'price', 'status', )
        skip_unchanged = True
        report_skipped = False
        dry_run = True

    def skip_row(self, instance, original):
        original_id_value = getattr(original, self._meta.import_id_field)
        instance_id_value = getattr(instance, self._meta.import_id_field)
        if original_id_value != instance_id_value:
            return True
        if not self._meta.skip_unchanged:
            return False
        for field in self.get_fields():
            try:
                if list(field.get_value(instance).all()) != list(field.get_value(original).all()):
                    return False
            except AttributeError:
                if field.get_value(instance) != field.get_value(original):
                    return False
        return True
```

Comment: That's a nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to not create new objects I think you'd need to override the [`import_row()`](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/resources.py#L418) within `ProductSyncResource`.

Then you could just do `if new: return`;

```
def import_row(self, row, instance_loader, using_transactions=True, dry_run=False, **kwargs):

    row_result = self.get_row_result_class()()
    try:
        self.before_import_row(row, **kwargs)
        instance, new = self.get_or_init_instance(instance_loader, row)
        self.after_import_instance(instance, new, **kwargs)
        if new:
            return row_result
        else:
            row_result.import_type = RowResult.IMPORT_TYPE_UPDATE
        row_result.new_record = new
        original = deepcopy(instance)
        ...
```

Following your comment about the preview error, just remember that this isn't an official feature of the app so you'll have to just follow stack traces & work around issues that popup. My first thought above looked like the quickest & easiest way to do this, but you could try to make the `else` for the save [save](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/resources.py#L459) conditional against new objects;

```
            elif not new:
                with transaction.atomic():
                    self.save_instance(instance, using_transactions, dry_run)
                self.save_m2m(instance, row, using_transactions, dry_run)
            diff.compare_with(self, instance, dry_run)
```

Comment: i think problem in other place.. on preview screen i got first error: ' (1048, "Column 'size_id' cannot be null")'. If i change column settings in database to allow Null, then in import screen i still have rows that 'will be added'

Comment: @NikitaBel Ok, well this isn't a feature so you'd have to keep playing with the override to see if you can get around this. Take a look at this line where it saves the instance. You could maybe do a check to not save if it's a new instance; https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/resources.py#L459